# Downloaded asset has bones but I cant manipulate them

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, asset

I have this asset that has bones listed in the Outliner but I cant seem to find the bones or manipulate them in Object or Edit view. It even has an animation that shows its bones working together and being animated. I've attached the blender file. Please instruct me on how to rig this thing so I can edit poses and create my own animations.
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: everything seems normal here, the bones are displayed as sticks, you can change that in the Object Data > Viewport Display > Display As and choose Octahedral for example. You can manipulate them in Edit mode or in Pose mode. You can't manipulate bones in Object mode, only the whole armature.